# Maven dependency weird bug

Tags: java, maven

I have 4 projects in my eclipse workspace. They are all 4 maven projects. The names are `API`, `Games`, `Faction`, `Board`.

`API` is used in all the other maven projects (`Games`, `Faction`, `Board`) and itself depends of a jar into my PC and also HikariCP.

I declare this dependencies in my API pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.github.paperspigot</groupId>
  <artifactId>paperspigot-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.10-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${basedir}\lib\paperspigot-1.7.10-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
  <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
  <version>2.7.8</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Then I declare on my 3 other projects that they depend of `API`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.onima</groupId>
  <artifactId>onimaapi</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

But I have a big warning on the API and the error log says this:

[image]

I don't understand why is there this error as I can code with the API in my classes. Can someone explain me? Thanks

**EDIT:** As requested the text of the screenshot:
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Project 'OnimaAPI' is missing required Java project: 'paperspigot'  OnimaAPI        Build path  Build Path Problem

---

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Project 'OnimaGames' is missing required Java project: 'onimaapi'   OnimaGames      Build path  Build Path Problem

I don't know why I can't set the `pom.xml` here so here's a link: https://ghostbin.com/paste/r4u62

Comment: Could you please convert the screenshot of the text back to plain text.

Comment: Did you update the project and build it again? Also can you share your complete pom.

Comment: you should "Maven->Update Project" (in eclipse) everytime you (substantially) change the pom! ...or you can eliminate the warnings, by manually adjusting (eclipse) project buildpath+assemebly

Comment: @SiKing I edited the post look at the end.

Comment: @ASR4 I did but still have the errors

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring `paperspigot` with `system` scope.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.github.paperspigot</groupId>
  <artifactId>paperspigot-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.7.10-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>${basedir}\lib\paperspigot-1.7.10-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

> Dependencies with the scope system are always available and are not looked up in repository. They are usually used to tell Maven about dependencies which are provided by the JDK or the VM.

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies

You should declare it with `compile` scope:

> This is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project. Furthermore, those dependencies are propagated to dependent projects.

Comment: that should't be a problem, given that he has defined an explicit systemPath along with the system scope, right?

Comment: I don't think the system dependency is propagated to dependent projects.

Comment: When I set the scope to compile it gives me an error (printscreen link) : http://prntscr.com/m79a84

Comment: The error tells you what to do, remove the `systemPath` property.

Comment: Have you got a link to the repository for the `paperspigot` dependency? Where did you get it from?

Comment: I got it from here https://github.com/IPVP-MC/Paper-1.7. Followed all the steps and got the jar plus the src

Comment: OK, so once you run `mvn install` the `paperspigot` JAR will be installed into your local maven repository (i.e. `~/.m2/repository/...`). You don't need to refer to a specific path, you just need to reference the `groupID`, `artifactID` and `version` in your POM and maven will find it in your local repo.

Comment: And how would I have the changes in my API if modify some code in `paperspigot` ? Thanks for all your help

Comment: Anytime you modify `paperspigot`, you need to build it and install it in your local repo (i.e. `mvn clean install`), then build the projects that depend on it and they will pull in the new JAR from your local repo.